# Http Delete Method in AngularJs with out url Binding?

Tags: angularjs, http

if using

```
  $http.delete('api/contacts', Id);
```

Then getting error

But When Using

```
   $http.delete('api/contacts/'+ Id);
```

Executing .

I don't Want to use URL Binding To pass data....

Please Help Me To Solve

Comment: Well.. http is desigigned delete by url. First read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Restiful API, the delete spec requires you to pass the id.

If you don't want to pass it through the url, then use POST but then your app will not be following restful api styles.

Answer (score 0):

$http.delete('api/contacts', {data: {id: 666}});

Try that, and have a read about the config object in angular $http.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage